# Want to unit test slack notification in laravel using PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, notifications, phpunit, slack

Help me to write unit test stub for slack notification is being sent or not. In the execution of one batch if the error occurs I am sending error in the slack channel.

Answer (score 0):

In tests you should use MockApplicationServices trait. It works pretty much the same as
[the documented event mocking.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mocking#mocking-events)

Usage is:

```
$this->expectsNotification($notifiable, $notification);

// eg.
$this->expectsNotification($user, UpperLimitExceeded::class);
```

There is also $this->withoutNotifications() to skip over any encountered notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But still, I am getting one error when my test stub calls method : $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\TestNotification($out, $slackChannelName));  Error is as below   1) Tests\Unit\ApplicationControllerTest::testBatch
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_App_Http_Controllers_ApplicationController::getKey does not exist.

Comment: There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\ApplicationControllerTest::testBatch
The following expected notification were not dispatched: [App\Http\Controllers\TestNotification]
Below is my source code  : $this->expectsNotification('test-slack',\App\Http\Controllers\TestNotification::class);]